# Передача значения из компонента к компоненту

Tags: javascript, angular2

Есть два независимых компонента они работают с одним сервисом. Если происходит действие в одном компоненте (пусть это будет клик) мне надо отобразить изменение во втором (увеличить счетчик), компоненты раздельные. Как передавать данные?

Comment: Посмотрите ответ в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698178/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-angular2/699451#699451

Answer (score 0):

Не могу быть уверен что так правильней всего, но как делаю я.
Вот пример сервиса.

```
private count= new Subject<any>();

  doSmth(message: string) {
    // тут вычисления
    this.count.next(newCountValue);
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.count.asObservable();
  }
```

Дальше в компонента(CountComponent) мы можем подписаться на обновления

```
this._serivce.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
  this.count = message;
});
```

И когда мы будем с любого другого компонета или сервиса вызывать

```
this._service.sendMessage("title");
```

или в любом методе сервиса

```
this.count.next(newCountValue);
```

то в нашем компоненте будут обновляться данные.

Вроде я это здесь читал когда то http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: Попробую более четко сформулировать вопрос.Есть CountComponent CardComponent и CardService. CardComponent вызывает CardService в котором идет  вычисление и обработка события с данными которые я передал в метод. Когда массив в сервисе достигает нужный length переменная this.count(в сервисе) увеличивается на 1ед. И мне надо если это увеличение произошло в template CountComponent  увеличить счетчик. Можно ли так сделать?

Comment: ну я так и написал. Берете этот count помещаете в subject, тогда он будет обновляться. (немного изменил ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private appServise:AppService){
    // this.counterStep=this.appServise.counterStep;
    // this.log(`constructor`);
}
```

моя ошибка была в том, что я приравнивал значение переменной сервиса к переменной компонента. А надо было вызвать переменную из сервиса и отобразить в template. Спасибо всем)

Answer (score 0):

А еще, помимо Rx сущностей есть стандартный EventEmitter - банальный pub/sub, кажется, это тут тоже может подойти. Идеологически, конечно, это не очень ивент, но что мешает передавать, скажем `{event: 'change some value', value: 'some new value'} ))`

App.service

```
public dynamicValue = new EventEmitter();
```

App.publisher

```
constructor(appService: AppService) {
  appService.dynamicValue.publish({...});
}
```

App.subscriber

```
constructor(appService: AppService) {
  appService.dynamicValue.subscribe(event => {
    ...
  });
}
```