# Как передать переменную из дочернего компонента в дочерний в Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Есть 3 компонента  : родительский **(P)** и 2 дочерних **(C1)** и **(C2)** (С1 и С2 - оба дочерние компоненты для Р и они не вложенные )
Template для P выглядит примерно так

```
<c1-component></c1-component>
<c2-component></c2-component>
```

В **с1** есть переменная **score**, которая **должна быть передана в с2**, где есть метод count_score () к ней будут добавляться или отниматься числа, а затем, обновленная переменная score **должна быть передана обратно в с1** из с2, посколько метод  count_score () будет вызываться несколько раз (соответственно, прибавлять значения или отнимать надо будет уже  с обновленной переменной). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему?

Насколько я поняла, можно через:

1. Shared Service
2. Template и EventEmittler (кажется, это лучший способ, я пыталась что-то сделать, как и остальные 2 способа, но не выходит)
3. передать из с1 в родителя, а оттуда спустить в с2, потом из с2 в родителя и оттуда в с1

Comment: первый вариант самый предпочтительный, храни логику в сервисе. Второй вариант вполне сносный, но наверное будет не таким очевидным. Третий, лучше не думать не о таком)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для коммуникации между **не вложенными компонентами** хорошо подходят Services.

Я покажу на примере того проекта, который у меня есть под рукой, а Вы уже легко сможете для своего случая адаптировать.

Рассмотрим вот такую структуру проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаем Service - recipe.service.ts:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model'; 

export class RecipeService {

  recipeSelected = new EventEmitter<Recipe>();

  private recipes: Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe('A Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Recipe_logo.jpeg'),
    new Recipe('Another Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Recipe_logo.jpeg')
  ];

  getRecipes(){
    return this.recipes.slice();
  }

}
```

Эта служба содержит какие-то данные, методы и для Вашего случая важно, что она содержит **событие recipeSelected**, которое посылает объект класса Recipe, - во всех компонентах, где будет доступна эта служба, будет доступно и это событие, в итоге его везде можно посылать и также везде можно принимать.

Теперь важно **подключить эту службу** на том уровне, на котором Вы хотите, чтобы она была доступна.
Если хотите, чтобы она была доступна по всем компонентам, то подключите её в *app.module.ts*. В моем случае она подключена в *recipe.component.ts* и будет доступна на этом уровне.
Подключение службы в секции **providers**.

recipe.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';
import { RecipeService } from './recipe.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.component.css'],
  providers: [ RecipeService ]
})
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedRecipe: Recipe;

  constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipeService.recipeSelected.subscribe(
      (recipe: Recipe) => {
        this.selectedRecipe = recipe;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Для того, чтобы служба была доступна для любого компонента в его конструкторе её нужно объявить. В этом компоненте Вы видите пример:

```
constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }
```

В этом же компоненте в методе ngOnInit() написан код как **слушать событие**, если какой-то компонент его послал:

```
this.recipeService.recipeSelected.subscribe(...);
```

Теперь остается посмотреть как **посылать событие через службу**.
Допустим, будем это делать из компонента recipe-item.

recipe-item.component.html:

```
<a
  href="#"
  class="list-group-item clearfix"
  (click)="onSelected()">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
  </div>
  <span class="pull-right">
        <img
          [src]="recipe.imagePath"
          alt="{{ recipe.name }}"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 50px;">
      </span>
</a>
```

По клику в этом компоненте будет вызван метод *onSelected()*, в нем событие генерится.

recipe-item.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Recipe } from '../../recipe.model';
import { RecipeService } from '../../recipe.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-item',
  templateUrl: './recipe-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-item.component.css']
})
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() recipe: Recipe;

  constructor(private recipeService : RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelected() {
    this.recipeService.recipeSelected.emit(this.recipe);
  }

}
```

В итоге, в данном примере в компоненте *recipe-item* генерится событие, и оно может быть передано в любой компонент, в котором подключена служба *RecipeService*. В нашем случае оно передаст данные в компонент *recipe*.

Более того, если объявить данную службу в *app.module.ts*, то её можно будет подключать в компонент *shopping-list* и передавать данные в него.